# Entity Framework 5 - Mapping Enums - Server Error in '/' Application. The specified type member 'xxx' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: enums, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have been having problems with enums not mapping in Entity Framework 5 (which supports enums).

When I call `results.Where(r => r.Category = LogEntry.LogCategory.ERROR)` where results is an IQueryable I get the Specified type member LogCategory is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

When I run migrations the Up() Method doesn't map the tables.

My model looks like this

```
public partial class LogEntry
{
public enum HttpMethod
{
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE
};

public enum LogCategory
{
    PAGE_VISIT,
    TRANSACTION,
    AUTHENTICATION,
    FAILED_AUTHENTICATION,
    EXCEPTION,
    INPUT_VALIDATION_ERROR,
    SPECIFICATION_FAILURE,
    SYSTEM,
    PAGE_NOT_FOUND,
    UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS

};

    public int LogId { get; set; }

    //public int? UserId { get; set; }
    //public virtual User user { get; set; }

    //public int? ForumId { get; set; }
    //public virtual Forum forum { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string ActiveRole { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public LogCategory Category { get; set; }

    public String Url { get; set; }
    public HttpMethod Method { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsAjaxRequest { get; set; }
    public String UserAgent { get; set; }
}
```

Anyone got any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out that the problem was a simple one. EF didn't like the enum being part of the LogEntry class. I moved it outside the class and suddenly it all works.

Thought I'd post this in case anyone else has the same problem as there was nothing that pointed me in the right direction already on SO!